# Table color text won't change

Tags: php, html, css, syntax, colors

I want to change the text colors in my table

That is all my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
    Lista:<br>
    <input type="text" name="camp_1">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <?php

        if (isset($_POST['camp_1'])){
            $var = $_POST['camp_1'];

            $var = str_replace(' ','', $var);

            $x = explode(',', $var);
            $odd = 1;
            $sum = 0;
            echo '<table>';

            for($i = 0; $i < count ($x) - 1; $i = $i + 2){
                if ( $odd ){
                    echo
                    '<tr>
                        <th>'.$x[$i].'</td>
                        <th>'.$x[$i + 1].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                else{
                    echo
                    '<tr>
                        <td>'.$x[$i].'</td>
                        <td>'.$x[$i + 1].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                $sum += $x[$i + 1];
                $odd = 1 - $odd; // comutes between 0 and 1
            }

            if ( $odd ){
                    echo
                    '<tr >
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>'.$sum.' $</th>
                    </tr>';
                }
                else{
                    echo
                    '<tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>'.$sum.' $</td>
                    </tr>';
                }   

            echo '</table>';


        }//if isset
    ?> 

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS file
Names style.css.

```
table th{
    background-color: green;
    color: #58FAD0;
}

td {
    color: #CC2EFA;
}
```

It just ignores whatever I write in my CSS file, regarding td and th
I must add that both files are in the same folder

Comment: Works ok for me using in-line CSS, have you linked your CSS file?

Comment: yes, like that:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
and both files are in the same folder :(

Comment: This is not a very good idea, `<th>` elements are cells in a ***table header*** and shouldn't be outputted like that at all, I'm guessing the browser is trying to fix your errors, and turns them into something else

Comment: Agreed with @adeneo but in terms of styling does the table show up at all? If so it it just black and white? Try adding:
    body { background-color: #000;
}

To your CSS and see if it changes the page to black

Comment: but they do it here and it works well :D 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_color

Comment: @Polaris yes, the table shows, but only the HTML part

Comment: And note how the `th` elements come before the `td` elements, it's because those are the headers, the elements at the top with the description

Comment: @Lyd Did you try the background trick to make sure your CSS file is linking correctly? Also make sure you have a <body> tag in your HTML of course

Comment: Also, this can be done with just plain CSS, making all the elements `td`, which is what they should be, and `table td:nth-child(odd) {background: green}`

Comment: Hmm, the page doesn`t change to black - and I do have a <body> tag

Comment: @Lyd Is the link in the <head> section of your page? Also check your CSS and make sure you haven't missed any semi-colons

Comment: table th{
 background-color: green;
    color: #58FAD0;
}
body { background-color: #000; 
}
td {
 color: #CC2EFA;
}
table td:nth-child(odd) {
background: green;
}


That's everything that is in my style.css file.

Comment: The only thing it could be now is the link between the PHP page and the CSS file. Can you post the entire PHP file?

Comment: of course, i have just edited my post

Comment: I dont see a problem with how it is linked. The only thing now is the file names and locations. If the file is definitely style.css and is in the root of the web files then I don't know what else to suggest

Comment: hey Lyd can ask you in what enviroment (server, browser)  run your PHP file?
do you work localy?

Comment: @Univese I use Apache ... I've moved both my files(PHP + CSS) to a different folder and everything works perfect... I still don't know what is the problemwhen I run it from the original folder

Comment: weird.. 
but nice to hear what works now..
Maybe was Apache who caused the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```css
table, th, tr{
    background-color: green;
    color: #58FAD0;
}

td {
    color: #CC2EFA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```